# Stored procedure multiplying values

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, left-join

I have 3 employees in my table. I'm using this stored procedure to try and loop through and display data for each individual employee. However it is returning the data for the first employee 3x and not returning anything for the other two employees. If I delete one employee out of my table, so I would have 2 employees, it returns data for the first employee 2x.

```
USE [Payroll]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[EmployeeProfitability] 
    @PayrollDate DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  
        0 AS Id, FirstName, LastName
    FROM
        dbo.Employees e
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT 
             EmployeeId
         FROM 
             dbo.EmployeeJobs ej
         WHERE 
             PayrollDate = @PayrollDate
         GROUP BY 
             ej.EmployeeId) AS Volume ON e.EmployeeId = Volume.EmployeeId
END
```

What I am getting returned to me is

```
Bob Saget
Bob Saget
Bob Saget
```

I am trying to get

```
Bob Saget
Ron Swanson
Dwayne Johnson
```

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. That includes DBMS (including version), a clear specification, cut & paste & runnable code (including input) & diffable expected output. Show that your program calculates what you expect it to as it goes through (sub)expression by saying what that is & showing that it actually does it via incremental output. Justify "minimal code with a problem" for required functionality by finding maximal code that works for part of that functionality. (This is basic debugging.)

Comment: Something is definitely missing. Either you have not pasted your entire query or you have not pasted your entire results. Whatever be the inner query, you have used a left join, it should return data from the first table no matter what as you don't have a where condition. That being said, please post a snapshot of the employee table with relevant columns and the result of the inner query of the Left join run separately. That would help in debugging the issue.

Comment: I removed a lot of the query because it isn't relevant to the issue. @FleminAdambukulam

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: You have edited but you have not given an [mcve]. Complete code running example input in a specific DBMS, etc. Per my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get duplicate row in your select caused by Id, FirstName, LastName. when you are trying left join  with a table which have a group by clause , you need to care about the first statement of your select.Like this:

```
SELECT  0 AS e.empoloyeeId, e.FirstName, e.LastName,
    Volume.Volume AS Volume,
    Volume.MaterialPct AS MaterialPct,
    Volume.LaborPct AS LaborPct,
    Volume.ProfitPct AS ProfitPct,
    Volume.Systems AS Systems,
    Volume.AOR AS AOR,
    Volume.Upgrade AS Upgrade,
    Volume.Condemned AS Condemned,
    Volume.TravelTime AS TravelTime,
    Volume.RegularHours AS RegularHours,
    Volume.OvertimeHours AS OvertimeHours
    from dbo.Employees e
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT EmployeeId, 
    SUM(Billing) AS Volume,
    SUM(Billing) / SUM(MaterialCost) AS MaterialPct,
    SUM(Billing) / SUM(Pay) AS LaborPct,
    SUM(Billing) / SUM(Profit) AS ProfitPct,
    SUM(System) AS Systems,
    SUM(AOR) AS AOR,
    SUM(Upgrade) AS Upgrade,
    SUM(Condemned) AS Condemned,
    SUM(TravelMinutes) AS TravelTime,
    SUM(RegularHours) AS RegularHours,
    SUM(OvertimeHours) AS OvertimeHours
    FROM dbo.EmployeeJobs ej
    WHERE PayrollDate = @PayrollDate
    GROUP BY ej.EmployeeId
) AS Volume ON
e.EmployeeId = Volume.EmployeeId
group by e.empoloyeeId, e.FirstName, e.LastName
```

Hope this work for you.

Comment: Your first paragraph is unintelligible. Even if it was clear it does not say enough to explain the problem.